# Передача объектов в функции JavaScirpt

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Частенько вижу такой код в js. `function({create}){}`.
В функцию передаётся объект. И я вот не понимаю, что это значит.
Мы делаем что-то типа `объект.create`, или `create.create`.
Я где-то слышал что это деструктуризация, или что-то в этом роде, но так толком и не понял.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment и дальше Деструктуризация объектов и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Действительно, здесь имеется в виду деструктуризация.
Скажем, имеется объект, содержащий поле c ключом `myFunc`

```
var obj = {
  myFunc: () => 'Я то-то создаю',
};
```

Положим, Вам понадобится использовать данное поле в функции `function toDoSomething() {}`
Прежде, до ES6, Вы, скорее всего, передавали бы в функцию объект `obj`. После чего изымали бы из него необходимое поле для удобства использования:

```
function toDoSomething(obj) {
  var myFunc = obj.myFunc; // myFunc использовать удобнее, чем obj.myFunc;
}
```

Теперь, благодаря деструктуризации, Вы можете сделать так:

```
function toDoSomething({myFunc}) {
// далее используете myFunc
}
```

Фактически, этой записью Вы избавили себя от написания строчки кода из предыдущего примера

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Уверен ты сэкономил много времени другим людям, в том числе и мне.
Я тебе очень благодарен:)

Comment: предлагаю Вам выяснить это, запустив следующий код: https://jsfiddle.net/spdc4gv9/2/

Comment: Строкой 'const { myFunc } = obj.myFunc;' Вы заставляете JS создать переменную myFunc и присвоить ей значение под ключом myFunc в функции obj.myFunc. Очевидно, что в этой функции нет такого свойства, поэтому в myFunc будет 'лежать' undefined. При вызове undefined в качестве функции Вы получаете ошибку. Убедитесь в этом сами